# Remove or customize the embeded form label

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

When I set up my formtype file like this:

```
$builder->add( 'producer', new ProducerType() );
```

it always return me a general title(label) for the embeded form, like "producer", how can I remove or customize this label?

UPDATE: the latest Fosuserbundle has been removed this annoyed lable

Answer (score 9):

The correct(?) way of removing the label is to set it to `false`.

```
$builder->add( 'producer', new ProducerType(), array( 'label' => false ));
```

Then the tag won't be rendered at all. Altough it's somehow missing in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html) at the moment, you can refactor this behaviour by looking at the default twig [form styles](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) (3rd line):

```
{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

Those twig styles are also a great start for form customization. More on this topic can be found in this [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: In my case 'label' of whole embedded form has appeared after `$view['form']->end($form)`. But when i try to pass `array('label' => false)` in `FormBuilder` it disappear. Thanks! +1

Comment: Searching on Google finding my own answer on SO... always a pleasure. :D

Answer (score 3):

you can try adding a label as an option, depending on what options ProductType is inheriting this may be enough.

```
$builder->add('producer', new ProducerType(), array('label' => 'Some Label'));
```

Comment: thank, I knew it, and how about remove it or add some decorators to it? like <div><label>...</div>

Comment: There's also `label_render` which you can set to false. Anything more advanced than that and you'll need to start modifying the twig templates

Answer (score 0):

To get an empty embedded form label try adding an empty (one space char) label attribute

```
$builder->add( 'producer', new ProducerType(), array('label' => ' '))
```

which results to something like the following:

```
<div id="producer">
  <div>
    <label class=" required"></label>
    <div id="mainEntityName_producer">
      <div>
        <label.../>
        <input.../>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rendering empty labels isn't the same as avoiding them at all. ;-)

Comment: Late in the day but marked down as this is really ugly and plain bad.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid fighting with formbuilder, you can disable labels using css.

```
<style>
    table.record_properties td label {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<form action="{{ path('equipment_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    <table class="record_properties" style="text-align: left;width: 500px;">
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <th>{% trans %}title{% endtrans %}</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>{{ form_row(edit_form.title) }}</td>
        </tr>
...
```